# Send text from Android phone to computer (OSX)

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to send data from my Android phone (running 4.3) to my computer. My phone will be outputting some data every couple of seconds, and I would like for my computer to display it. Just displaying it on the terminal would be fine.

I've looked into BlueCove and it is just broken. It is using deprecated calls and it simply doesn't work.

So how do I do this?

I'm just sending ASCII text every couple of seconds.

I've also looked at the bluetooth sample app. However, I don't know how to make the text appear on my computer screen. (Admittedly, the app was meant to work with Android phones.)

Is what I'm asking even possible?

Side note: This doesn't need to be complicated. In fact, I would prefer something down and dirty. I'm just going to be using the output for debugging and testing.

Comment: Do you *have* to use bluetooth for this? If you're just looking for debug output, are the existing Android development tools not sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: Given the nature of my project, typical development tools will not suffice. I need to see the output of the phone when it is inside someone's pocket. That said, if you (or someone) thinks that there is a better/easier way to go other than bluetooth, I'm all ears.

Comment: Web Service? If both devices are on the same Wifi AP you don't need a cloud based server.

Comment: It will be easy if you can use a web server, or if you can create a server in your computer or in your phone and comunicate by means of your wifi network (as Airdroid does, for example)

If its only for testing, probably it will be enough if you send emails to you form the phone. It will be easier than bluetooth

Comment: What would be the easiest way to connect devices? And how do you do it?